# mongodb not erroring with wrong uri

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having big problems trying to wrap my head around mongodb.

First of all, I tried using mongoose, but I really don't like its schemas, I want to have my own classes, and perform CRUD operations in a classic style.

So I moved on and started using mongodb. I think I already gonna give up and use MySQL, because I find their documentation very very obscure, and also no public issue tracker on github.

Anyway, my problem is that if I connect to a non existing db or to a non existing host, mongodb isn't showing any error.

My code:

```
const mongodb     = require( 'mongodb' ),
      MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let db_uri = `mongodb://${config.host}:${config.port}/${config.name}`;
MongoClient.connect( db_uri, function( err, mongoclient ) {
  console.log( err );
});
```

Assume that config.host or config.port are not correct.

err is alway null.

Why is this ?

Comment: Is that directly copied from your code?  If so then your db_uri is not a string, you are missing a starting quotation mark.  Also there is a github https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: @curtainrising yeah, for some reason it was lost on the copy process :D But that was not the problem ;) I will edit the question, thanks.

Comment: So I tested it out.  Just like when connecting to mongodb through command line, you can connect to any database without error.  It automatically creates it for you.  BUT it will not make it permanent until you do an insert/create a collection.

Comment: hm... what you said makes sense, though, I don't think it makes sense to behave like that ...

Comment: the driver does error out as shown in this test case https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/f6448bec1e76f21019a9fdb6452514905301c88c

Comment: @christkv I guess curtainrising is also right. It error for wrong host and/or port, but not for an inexistent database. I think this should be reflected on the documentation or maybe even fixed. Which use case is this a desired behavior? Anyway, thank you so much for your answer. I would happily update the docs and do a PR if I know where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does this great(and in some cases really annoying thing if you have fat fingers) where if you attempt to connect a database that doesn't exist, it will create it for you.  I knew it did this in command line, but it appears it does it with this code as well.  Using the insert code from the [npm node instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) I was able to test and verify this.

Edit- removing example and adding something actually helpful

It may be cumbersome, but there is a way to test if a collection exists.  You ask if an index exists.

```html
const mongodb     = require( 'mongodb' ),
      MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var db_uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/newDb";
MongoClient.connect( db_uri, function( err, db ) {
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    collection.indexExists(0, function(err, indexExists){
  });
});
```